# Running mocha test can't find module from absolute path

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mocha.js, next.js, ts-node

My tests are working properly if I set relative path. But if it's absolute path, I get an:  "Cannot find module 'src/types/jssb'" error.

My tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
  "target": "es5",
  "lib": [
    "dom",
    "dom.iterable",
    "esnext"
  ],
  "allowJs": true,
  "skipLibCheck": true,
  "strict": true,
  "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
  "noEmit": true,
  "esModuleInterop": true,
  "module": "esnext",
  "moduleResolution": "node",
  "resolveJsonModule": true,
  "isolatedModules": true,
  "jsx": "preserve",
  "baseUrl": "./",
  "paths": {
    "src/*": ["./src/*"]
  }
 },
 "exclude": [
  "node_modules"
 ],
 "include": [
   "next-env.d.ts",
   "declarations",
   "**/*.ts",
   "**/*.tsx"
 ]
}
```

In package.json I set test script to:

```
"test": "TS_NODE_COMPILER_OPTIONS='{\"module\":\"commonjs\"}' node_modules/mocha/bin/mocha -r ts-node/register test/**/*.test.ts",
```

Here is my test file

```
import { assert } from 'chai';

import { Program } from '../src/types/program';
import { calculateProgramPayment } from '../src/utils/calculator/payment';
import { DepositInput, LoanInput } from '../src/types/calculator';

describe('sample', function() {
  it('sample', function() {});
});
```

*calculateProgramPayment* refers to a payment.ts.
And in payment.ts I have:

```
import { Program } from 'src/types/program';
import { InterimPropertyType, PreliminaryLoanType } from 'src/types/jssb';
```

If I change it to '../src/types/jssb' it works. But that forces me to change whole projects path.

Comment: I'm always starting import paths with `./` `../` `/` to avoid strange behavior. ;)

Comment: Yeah, all packages that are imported are relative by default unless you use some special tooling (Babel with regular JS, or Babel with TypeScript). Check out this medium article about absolute imports with TypeScript: https://medium.com/@grrowl/fixing-absolute-imports-in-typescript-797f405176eb